# Using Python to optimize a linear programming problem with a fraction as a constraint

Tags: python, linear-programming, pyomo

I am trying to solve the following linear programming problem with a constraint that requires at least 10% of each ingredient. The problem is asking that the solution consists of at least 10% seeds, 10% raisins, 10% flakes, 10% pecans, and 10% walnuts. At the moment I have the constraints set up under "#ingredients" but am not able to figure out how to make the value 10%. I am using the fraction method, but I continue to get the following error.

[image: invalid syntax error]

```
from fractions import Fraction as Fraction
# declare the model
model = ConcreteModel()

# declare decision variables
model.seeds = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.raisins = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.flakes = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.peacans = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.walnuts = Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)


# declare objective
model.cost = Objective(
                  expr = 4*model.seeds + 5*model.raisins + 3*model.flakes + 7*model.peacans + 6*model.walnuts,
                  sense = minimize)

# declare constraints
# Vitamin Content
model.Vitamins = Constraint(expr = 10*model.seeds + 20*model.raisins + 10*model.flakes + 30*model.peacans + 20*model.walnuts >= 20)
# Mineral Content
model.Minerals = Constraint(expr = 5*model.seeds + 7*model.raisins + 4*model.flakes + 9*model.peacans + 2*model.walnuts >= 10)
# Protein Content
model.Protein = Constraint(expr = 1*model.seeds + 4*model.raisins + 10*model.flakes + 2*model.peacans + 1*model.walnuts >= 15)
# Calorie Content
model.Calories = Constraint(expr = 500*model.seeds + 450*model.raisins + 160*model.flakes + 300*model.peacans + 500*model.walnuts >= 600)
#ingredients
# Seed Constraint
model.Seeds = Constraint(expr = model.seeds >= (Fraction(1, 10))
# Raisin Constraint
model.Raisin = Constraint(expr = model.raisins >= (Fraction(1,10))
#Flakes Constraint
model.Flakes = Constraint(expr = model.flakes >= (Fraction(1,10))
# Peacans Constraint
model.Peacans = Constraint(expr = model.peacans >= (Fraction(1,10))
# Walnuts Constraint
model.Walnuts = Constraint(expr = model.walnuts >= (Fraction(1,10))

# show the model you've created
model.pprint()
```

Comment: Does `(model.seeds / (model.seeds + model.raisins + model.flakes + model.peacans + model.walnuts)) >= 0.10` do it?  And can you fix the spelling of `peacans`?  ;)

Comment: @Tim Roberts 

That did work, but it did not return the optimal values that the professor posted, so I do not think it worked properly. Thank you for your response and yes I will correct the spelling of pecans haha.

Comment: I would suggest writing down the mathematical formulation on a piece of paper first. E.g. `x(i) should be at least 10% of total` can be formulated as  `y=sum(i,x(i))` and `x(i)>=0.1*y`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a right parenthesis on the previous line.

model.Seeds = Constraint(expr = model.seeds >= (Fraction(1, 10))

Count 'em: you've got 3 lefts and two rights. Same for the Raisins line and the following lines.

When you get syntax errors, that's always a likely culprit.

Comment: thank you for the response, I added a third parenthesis to the right side so the code looks like model.Seeds = Constraint(expr = model.seeds >= (Fractions(1,10))), but i get this error

AttributeError: 'Fraction' object has no attribute 'is_expression_type'

Comment: Looks like you've got more learning and debugging to go then!